# Strange issue with background image and border-radius in IE11

Tags: html, css

Here is test link:
http://bybyweb.com/cafe-vert/. 
Problem:
In IE11 there is strange empty (?) space at the right hand side of 'product box': "PERDEZ PLUS DE 10KG etc,etc...." - part (green box and 3 white boxes at the left hand side). It seems that background image doesn't 'stretch' to container width (container width changing doesn't solve problem).

In Firefox and Chrome, all looks perfect.

Relevant code: HTML

```
<div class="product-box first-box">
<h4>PERDEZ PLUS DE 10KG - Achetez 3 MOIS et obtenez 2 gratuitS! </h4>
</div>
<div class="product-box ">
<h4>PERDEZ entre 5 et 10 kg - Achetez 2 MOIS et obtenez 1 gratuit! </h4>
</div>
<div class="product-box ">
<h4>PERDEZ ENTRE 3 ET 5 KG - ACHETEZ 1 MOIS DE CURE!</h4>
</div>
<div class="product-box ">
<h4>DERNIÈRE CHANCE !! - Achetez 1 MOIS et obtenez 1 gratuit! </h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product-box {
    width:598px;
    height:210px;
    border:1px solid #0b7564;
        background-position:center top;
border-radius:7px;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 7px 15px -10px rgba(112,108,112,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 7px 15px -10px rgba(112,108,112,1);
box-shadow: 2px 7px 15px -10px rgba(112,108,112,1);
margin-bottom:23px;
background-image:url(../images/product-bar.png);
background-position:top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

 background-clip:border-box;
}
```

I guess it is related to border-radius using, but, i can't find IE (11, and probably lower versions) fix... Thanks in advance!

Comment: p.s. using of regular image on place of background image + absolutely positioned text seems like fix, but... it is dirty and requires additional coding... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the best answer, but setting the width of .product-box to 597px seems to clean it up for me.

Comment: Actually, it is good answer! Worked for me, too. Thanks! (when i experimented with width, didn't tried with odd numbers:))